# Slow download speed with Nginx or scp

Tags: nginx, networking

My questions may seem a duplicate of the other that exist but I didn't find one that fixes my issue.

So I have an ARM server with 250Mb connection (up and down). My torrent client (rtorrent) can download and upload at that speed but I can't reach that speed when downloading a static file hosted by Nginx or using scp. I have the issue when streaming. My speed is capped at 0.5MB/s.

First I though the problem is related to IO or the process power. I made some changes to Nginx config and disabled SSL for static files but that didn't fix the problem.

Recently I found out that when I download multiple files, each download is capped at 0.5MB/s. I did reach my Internet full speed by downloading 10 files simultaneously.

So why I can't reach my full speed with only one single download?

Comment: can you please add this to your server block -  proxy_download_rate 0;
    proxy_upload_rate 0;

Comment: I will try that in a couple of hours. But what about scp?

Comment: Sounds to me like an MTU problem

Comment: @wurtel How do you fix that? Doing pings show packets loss.

Comment: Have you considered the ISP may be the source of the problem (or latency/packet loss + TCP slowdowns)

Comment: @Hunsu packet loss with ping is not an indication of MTU problems; only when you use `-s` to set a packet size (excluding the 8 bytes of ICMP header data).